# How to get div content in javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the content of a `div` in a JavaScript variable.

I did try some code:

```
<html>
     <head>
         <script>
             function data(){
                 alert();
                 var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('newdata') 
                 alert(MyDiv1);
             }
         </script>
    </head>

    <body>
         <div id="newdata" style="background-color: red; width: 100px;height: 50px;">
             1 <!-- The content I'm trying to get -->
         </div>
         <a href="" onclick="data();">Logout</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

But it does not work correctly.

Comment: `var content = MyDiv1.innerHTML;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('newdata')
alert(MyDiv1)
```

it should be

```
var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('newdata').innerHTML
alert(MyDiv1)
```

OR

```
var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('newdata')
alert(MyDiv1.innerHTML)
```

With `.innerHTML` you will get the `html` of specified `element` in the `DOM`.

**EDIT:-**

[**SEE DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6v3gkq1t/)

Comment: how can i change color of div  if value is 1 and if value is 2 then remain same

Answer (score 1):

You must use **innerHTML**.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="newdata" style="background-color: red; width: 100px;height: 50px;">
        1
    </div>

    <a href="" onclick="data();">Logout</a>
</body>

    <script>
        function data() {
            var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('newdata').innerHTML;
            alert(MyDiv1);
        }
    </script>

</html>
```